# How to stop jquery from overriding CSS color?

Tags: jquery, html, css, colors

I have a table that shows name, rank, and points. Rows change color when I hover over them and When I click on each individual row, it adds the class of 'active'. My CSS rules select the 'active' class to give it a border and new background color. The border works, but the background color doesn't.

I know the jquery is working because when I click on the row, it adds a black border as it should according the CSS rules I set, but the background just turns and stays plain white. I checked firebug too which shows the active class being added to the clicked row but the color still doesn't change. I'm not worried about toggle clicking right now because I just want to get this first step cleared.

I searched a few other older posts that recommended adding !important, but that's not working either.

Html

```
  <tr class="row-data">
    <td class="name">player</td>
    <td class="points">points</td>
    <td class="rank"><p id="rank">Rank1</p></td>
  </tr>
```

css

```
  .row-data .active {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: red !important;
```

}

Jquery

```
$(function() {
var limegreen = '#73f302';
var white2 = '#eef4cc';
var transitionTime = '0.5s'

var $rankTable = $('.rank-table');
var $rowData = $rankTable.find('.row-data');

function rowHighlight() {
  var rowID = $(this)

  rowID.css({
    'background-color': limegreen,
    'transition-property': 'background-color',
    'transition-duration': transitionTime,
  });
};
function rowDelight() {
  var rowID = $(this)
  rowID.css({
    'background-color': white2,
    'transition-property': 'background-color',
    'transition-duration': transitionTime,
  });
};

function activeToggle() {
  var activeID = $(this)

  activeID.addClass('active')
};

$rowData.on('mouseover', rowHighlight);
$rowData.on('mouseleave', rowDelight);
$rowData.on('click', activeToggle);


});
```

Comment: The problem is that you try to target ```.row-data .active``` when by your code i guess you should be targeting ```.rank-table .active``` or ```.row-data.active```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, your `.active` class doesn't work because you've added a combinator (space) to the selector. `.row-data .active` means "find all children with the class `.active` inside `.row-data`". You'd want `.row-data.active` to find `.row-data` with the `.active` class.

In regards to the rest, Javascript styles are applied inline, which means they override any styles defined in a style tag or external stylesheet - unless you use `!important` on those rules. Read: [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Having said that, what you want to do is **exactly** what CSS classes are for. Create your styles in CSS, and toggle the classes with javascript. You should never set styles with Javascript, *especially* not if you then have to go and use `!important` in your stylesheets! There's always a way to do it with CSS.

CSS:

```
.row-data {
  transition: background-color .5s;
}

.row-data.active {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: red;
}

.row-data.highlight {
  background-color: #73f302;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
  var $rankTable = $('.rank-table');
  var $rowData = $rankTable.find('.row-data');

  $rowData.on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
  });

  $rowData.on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
  });

  $rowData.on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: @KnT88 Awesome, really glad it helped! Brad's answer is even better; there's no need to even use Javascript to bind the `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` events (unless you're doing something else in the code). You can just use CSS `:hover`.

Answer (score 3):

First, set your hover state with CSS.
And for the active state you're looking for, simply toggle the class.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j07scwxj/)

HTML

```
<body>
  <table>
    <tr class="row-data">
      <td class="name">bob</td>
      <td class="points">12 points</td>
      <td class="rank">
        <p>Rank1</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='row-data'>
      <td class="name">bill</td>
      <td class="points">6 points</td>
      <td class="rank">
        <p>Rank2</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

CSS

```
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.row-data:hover{
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.row-data.active{
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: red;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
  $('.row-data').on('click', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
})
```

Comment: Now I feel silly; of course there's no need to even use Javascript to toggle the `highlight` class. +1.

Comment: Yeah but you took the time to explain it all out so there's that :)

Comment: Why was my answer down voted? It is the correct answer and it is the best answer.... Can I even find out who down voted it? What a goofy system this is.

Comment: I've got heaps of them mate. Nothing you can do to find out who or why. You're right - if someone wants to downvote, they should be forced to write a comment explaining why.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are using `.css` to set the style on mouseover and mouseleave. That causes the css to be inlined in the html in a `style=""` attribute.

Inline styling has the highest importance so no matter what you set your class to it won't work.

Instead what you should do is to move your css for `mouseover` and `mouseleave` into a class and set the classes instead of using `.css`